# Changing breaks on a geom_tile() heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, geom-tile

I am working on the following dataframe:

```
structure(c(NA, 52, 22, 52, 111, 0, 3, 16, 5, 0, 0, 80, NA, 14, 
243, 14, 41, 1, 177, 3, 0, 20, 26, 8, NA, 13, 21, 10, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 59, 29, 7, NA, 15, 20, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 111, 9, 273, 1733, 
NA, 60, 3, 14, 164, 0, 8, 20, 171, 53, 932, 135, NA, 0, 33, 3, 
0, 144, 21, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, NA, 1, 0, 0, 0, 23, 81, 14, 146, 20, 
19, 5, NA, 1, 1, 0, 11, 4, 4, 8, 11, 0, 2, 12, NA, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
4, 32, 0, 16, 0, 3, 0, NA, 0, 0, 40, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 
NA), .Dim = c(11L, 11L), .Dimnames = list(c("WILL_", "WOULD_", 
"MAY_", "MIGHT_", "CAN_", "COULD_", "SHALL_", "SHOULD_", "MUST_", 
"OUGHT TO_", "USED TO_"), c("_WILL", "_WOULD", "_MAY", "_MIGHT", 
"_CAN", "_COULD", "_SHALL", "_SHOULD", "_MUST", "_OUGHT TO", 
"_USED TO")))
```

And I have the following plot:

```
reshape2::melt(twitter_us_no_clit_matrix_nohave, value.name = "Freq") %>%
  mutate(label = ifelse(is.na(Freq) | Freq == 0, "", as.character(Freq))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Var2, fct_rev(Var1))) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Freq), color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "grey", high = "purple", na.value = "black") +
  scale_x_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0, 0), position="top") +
  scale_y_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=60,vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0))
```

[image]

It's all looking good but I'm trying to figure out how to change the breaks so that it changes the heatmap and its "Freq" label accordingly.

The breaks would be  `c(0,1,5,10,50,100,500,100000)` and would make the values look more or less like the following in terms of colour heat:

[image]

Which exact lines should I tweak in my geom_tile()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to divide your continuous scale into steps. I [had some success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckXku.png) using the `scale_fill_steps()` function:

```r
library(tidyverse)

twitter_us_no_clit_matrix_nohave <- structure(c(NA, 52, 22, 52, 111, 0, 3, 16, 5, 0, 0, 80, NA, 14, 
            243, 14, 41, 1, 177, 3, 0, 20, 26, 8, NA, 13, 21, 10, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 59, 29, 7, NA, 15, 20, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0, 111, 9, 273, 1733, 
            NA, 60, 3, 14, 164, 0, 8, 20, 171, 53, 932, 135, NA, 0, 33, 3, 
            0, 144, 21, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, NA, 1, 0, 0, 0, 23, 81, 14, 146, 20, 
            19, 5, NA, 1, 1, 0, 11, 4, 4, 8, 11, 0, 2, 12, NA, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
            4, 32, 0, 16, 0, 3, 0, NA, 0, 0, 40, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0, 
            NA), .Dim = c(11L, 11L), .Dimnames = list(c("WILL_", "WOULD_", 
                                                        "MAY_", "MIGHT_", "CAN_", "COULD_", "SHALL_", "SHOULD_", "MUST_", 
                                                        "OUGHT TO_", "USED TO_"), c("_WILL", "_WOULD", "_MAY", "_MIGHT", 
                                                                                    "_CAN", "_COULD", "_SHALL", "_SHOULD", "_MUST", "_OUGHT TO", 
                                                                                    "_USED TO")))

breaks <- c(0,1,5,10,50,100,500,100000)

reshape2::melt(twitter_us_no_clit_matrix_nohave, value.name = "Freq") %>%
  mutate(label = ifelse(is.na(Freq) | Freq == 0, "", as.character(Freq))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Var2, fct_rev(Var1))) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Freq), color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), color = "black") +
  scale_fill_steps(low = "grey", high = "purple", breaks = breaks, na.value = "black") + 
  scale_x_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0, 0), position="top") +
  scale_y_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=60,vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0))
```

However, given the varying distance between your breaks, most of the scale is in gray. I don't know if you want to preserve that perspective.

For rescaling the colors, change the line to

```r
scale_fill_steps(low = "grey", high = "purple", breaks = breaks, na.value = "grey", trans = "log")
```

which will make them [evenly distributed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwZ5h.png) in your scale. I was unsuccessful at setting them manually. I changed the color of the `NA` value, because now all your zeroes are `NA`s due to the log transformation.

Comment: That's already quite helpful, thanks ! How would you get around to setting a color for each break manually? Just in case that's useful, the second heatmap in my question is based on a colour palette called "Purples2" which seems to go from this light grey to a deep purple. I'm trying to find out what colours that palette is made of, to set those colours manually unless there's an automatic alternative

Comment: I have added the code for log transformation of the colors, which will make the steps look even.

Comment: Looks even better and perfectly what I'm looking for, thanks ! Reproducing the exact code you provide I have a small error : can't find scale_fill_steps() function. Is this normal?

Comment: I just tried it out in a fresh session and had no issues. The [scale_fill_steps](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_steps.html) is part of the ggplot2 package, I have version 3.3.3

Comment: Just updated to R 4.0 and it works. Thanks, looks great !

Comment: yes, if you change all the Freq values that equal 0 to a small number (like 0.001) and then replace 0 in your breaks with that number.